# Use custom join query with Django ManyToMany relationship

Tags: python, django

I have a `User` model which connects to a `Role` model via a ManyToMany, and then the `Role` model connects to two models, `SitePermission` or `ForumPermission`. Problem is, I can't figure out how to setup that connection.

Here are my models, with (I believe) irrelevant fields removed.

Role:

```
class Role():
    class RoleTypes(models.TextChoices):
        SITE = "s", "Site"
        FORUM = "f", "Forum"

    role_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=RoleTypes.choices, null=True)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        "permissions.Permission",
        related_name="roles",
        through="permissions.RolePermissions",
    )
```

RolePermissions:

```
class RolePermissions():
    role = models.ForeignKey("permissions.Role", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    permission = models.ForeignKey("permissions.SitePermission", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

SitePermissions:

```
class SitePermissions():
    permission = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

ForumPermissions:

```
class SitePermissions():
    permission = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    forum = models.ForeignKey(
        "forums.forum", db_column="forumId", on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
```

Problem of course, is that I can't connect multiple tables to the ManyToMany. If I was doing it in SQL, I'd have something like `roles r LEFT JOIN role_permissions rp_s ON r.type = 's' and r.id = rp.role_id INNER JOIN site_permissions sp ON rp_s.permission_id = sp.id` with a second set of joins for forum_permissions (I know that SQL isn't exactly right, more for example).

So is there a way to accomplish this? Conditionally link to multiple tables? Or do I need to have a separate property in `Role` for each `SitePermission` and `ForumPermission`, and then have logic for each to utilize it?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RolePermissions.objects.raw("roles r LEFT JOIN role_permissions rp_s ON r.type = 's' and r.id = rp.role_id INNER JOIN site_permissions sp ON rp_s.permission_id = sp.id")
```

Comment: Heh, so I know I can use the raw syntax, I was more curious if there's a Django way of doing this.

Comment: I guess there is not. SO far, I have not found a way either. I am coming from RoR and I am a bit disappointed that there is no "Django way" to do this. Oh well...maybe when I become a bit more comfortable with Python and Django I'll do a PR :-p